# How to delete post and delete tag which will be unused on Django2.2 using django-taggit

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-taggit

I'm making a blogapp which uses django and django-taggit. I made a deleteview using `django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView`. But when I saw the admin page, the post was deleted but tag was not. How can I delete the post and delete the tag which will be unused at the same time?

This is the code that I tried.
If you remove the `delete` function, it will only delete the post.

**views.py**

```
class DeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.edit.DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('portal:index')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        deltag = self.object.tags.clear()
        result = super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return deltag,result
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):


    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('portal:index')
```

Comment: What's the relation between Post and Tags, can you update the question with the models? If Tag has a ForeignKey to Post, you can use ```on_delete=models.CASCADE``` when you define the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced that you can remove the tags that are related to a `Post`, since another `Post` might use some of these tags as well.

What you can do is delete the `Tag`s that are no longer in use:

```
from taggit.models import Tag

class DeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.edit.DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('portal:index')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
        Tag.objects.filter(post=None).delete()
        return result
```

Note however that often tags are not only used for one model (like a `Post`), but are used accross several models. So removing unused tags by the `Post` model, is likely not a good idea, since a `Comment`, or `Product`, etc. could still use the given tag.